# How to dump large mysql databse faster ?

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database which is in size of 4 TB and when I'm dumping it using mysqldump then it is taking around 2 days to dump that database in the .sql format

Can anyone help to faster this process?

OS ubuntu 14 
MySQL 5.6 
The single database of size 4 TB 
hundreds of table average tables size is around 100 to 200 GB

Please help if anyone have any solution to this

Comment: rewrite the mysqldump utility? Get better hardware? The process used by mysql is not really in your control, unless you intend to make a new version of the software. Perhaps you ought to export it in smaller chunks. I don't know how big the resulting .sql is, or what you intend to do with it, but it's probably going to be unwieldy

Comment: You could also explore alternative backup strategies: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html

Comment: I have a slave server in place and to make slave sync with master I'm doing this dumps

Comment: Copy the table files, not the dump. 4TB database would mean 10-20 TB of dump file.  Do you have really a so large disk?

Comment: For a master/slave scenario would you not be better off with replication? (See that link I gave you).

Comment: First I was on aws rds and there they use to provide me daily snapshot backups but now I have moved to some other provider with virtual machine of above specification so I'm trying to find the backup solution I know slave would be great for taking backups but I want daily copies of backup in format of .sql so I can revert backups in case I required

Comment: Copying files is a lot better, also to revert all or single records. If you have replication you have also all the changes in replication logs. Do not think that importing a dump into mysql is quick.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- stop the database,
- copy the files in a new database
- restart the database
- process the data from the new place (maybe in an other machine).

If you are replicating, just stop replication, process, start replication.

These methods should improve speed, because of lack of concurrent processes that access the database (and all lock logic).

On such large databases, I would try not to have to make dumps. Just use mysql table files if possible.

In any case 2 days seems a lot, also for a old machine. Check that you are not swapping, and try to check your mysql configuration for possible problems.  In general, try to get a better machine. Computer are cheaper than time to optimize.

Comment: My master server have decent specification it have 54 virtual cores 512 GB ram and 8 TB storage. Yes but I believe I;m struggling with iops here hence it is taking 2 days to complete dump file and dump file size is 1.5 TB after completion

Comment: First I was on aws rds and there they use to provide me daily snapshot backups but now I have moved to some other provider with virtual machine of above specification so I'm trying to find the backup solution I know slave would be great for taking backups but I want daily copies of backup in format of .sql so I can revert backups in case I required